# FileReference: post file without browsing

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to upload a file to the server. I'm doing it like this:

```
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
fileRef.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, normalprogressHandler);
fileRef.browse();

function selectHandler(event:flash.events.Event):void
{
    var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    params.date = new Date();
    params.ssid = "94103-1394-2345";
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.test.com/Uploads"); 
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = params;

    fileRef.upload(request, "Custom1");
}

function completeHandler(event:flash.events.Event):void
{
    trace("uploaded");
}

function normalprogressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var percent:Number = Math.floor((event.bytesLoaded * 100)/ event.bytesTotal );
    trace(percent+"%");
}
```

Would it be possible to upload a file but without browsig for it? I want to decide myself what file to upload instead of the user performing a browse first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with `FileReference` which has the following limitations ([reference](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/)):

1. The `load()` and `save()` APIs can only be called in response to user
   interaction (such as a button click).
2. The locations of the loaded and save files are not exposed to
   ActionScript.
3. The APIs are asynchronous (non-blocking).

Clearly, it would represent a major security risk if the Flash player was arbitrarily allowed to upload anything from your local file system to a remote server.

If you're trying to upload from an AIR app, you can do what you're trying to do with the [`File`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but would append: as an installed AIR application you have this ability. Just not as flash run in the browser or standalone plugin.

Comment: Thanks Plastic Sturgeon; I guess I should have asked for clarification before attempting to answer. I've updated the answer with your suggestion.